# Solution of : SPOJ : DSUBSEQ

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

My code is giving wrong answer for the following question. I have tried many test cases but can't find the error.

http://www.spoj.com/problems/DSUBSEQ/

```
# include<bits/stdc++.h>
# define lli long long int
# define pb push_back
# define loop(i,a,b) for(int i=a;i<b;i++)
# define loopl(i,a,b) for(lli i=a;i<b;i++)
# define MAXN 1000
#define INF 1000000000
# define mod 1000000007
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int t;
   cin>>t;
   while(t--)
   {
     string s;
     cin>>s;
     int n=s.length();
     int visited[26],dp[n+1];
     memset(visited,-1,26);
     loop(i,0,26) visited[i]=-1;
     dp[0]=1;
     loop(i,1,n+1)
     {
            dp[i]=2*dp[i-1];

            if(visited[s[i-1]-'A']!=-1) dp[i]=(dp[i]%mod-dp[visited[s[i-1]-'A']]%mod + mod)%mod ;

            visited[s[i-1]-'A'] = i-1 ;
     }

    cout<<dp[n]<<endl;
   }

}
```

Sample test Cases:

INPUT:

- 3
- AAA
- ABCDEFG
- CODECRAFT

OUTPUT:

- 4
- 128
- 496

But i am getting : wrong answer #1

This language is c++ . I am new to dynamic programming.

Comment: Do you know an input case that produces incorrect results? If so, you should try debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: Don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and the other macro crap. ever. If you're worried about typing stuff like a few `#include` lines or a for loop, you need to work on your typing speed. Terrible "time saving" practices often make programs much harder to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input contains lower test cases also.
It will be a good thing to convert every character to upper case

Update: Another thing you are doing wrong is not taking mod in this line `dp[i]=2*dp[i-1]`
Imagine a test where there are distinct 26 letters in that case ans will 2^26 will certainly overflow
Make it `dp[i]=(2*dp[i-1])%mod`

Comment: In the question it is given that it only contain upper case letters.

Comment: Sometimes they do deflect from the constraints

Comment: Without taking the note of lower case letters, just taking the mod of dp[i] at every step solved my problem.

Comment: Ohk. I encountered a problem on SPOJ where it deflected from its constraint so thought here might be also